# Average columns in 3d array

Tags: python, numpy

I have a list like

```
list = [[[3, 10, 8.53, 0.46], [3, 11, 7.02, 0.53]],
 [[3, 10, 9.03, 0.42], [3, 11, 7.54, 0.55]]]
```

I want to do the average so that I get a list like:

```
[[3, 10, 8.78, 0.44], [3, 11, 7.28, 0.54]]
```

The first and second columns are the same so I want to keep the integer values. What I'm doing right now is giving me the first two columns as floats. I'd also like to convert the result back to a list.

```
>>> a = np.array(list)
>>> numpy.mean(a, axis=0)
[[ 3.   10.    8.78  0.44]
 [ 3.   11.    7.28  0.54]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to do something like this:

```
a = np.array(list)
[[int(val) if val.is_integer() else val for val in i] for i in a.mean(0)]
#[[3, 10, 8.78, 0.44], [3, 11, 7.279999999999999, 0.54]]
```

But I think you would be better off looping your list in the first place. Or use structured array to have multi dtype in the same array.

Comment: Could you round it to two decimals.

Comment: @Arturo Simply replace `else val` with `else round(val,2)`